# $http doesn't send cookie in Requests

Tags: html, angularjs, webkit, xmlhttprequest

We are working on a RESTful Webservice with AngularJS and Java Servlets.
When the user logs in, our backend sends a "Set-Cookie" header to the frontend. In Angular we access the header via `$cookies` (ngCookie - module) and set it.
[image]

Now that the user is logged in he can for example delete some stuff. Therefore the frontend sends a GET request to the backend. Because we work on different domains we need to set some CORS Headers and Angular does an OPTIONS request before the actual GET request:

**OPTIONS request:**
[image: OPTIONS request]

**GET request**
[image: GET request]

We do this in Angular via $http module, but it just won't send the cookie, containing `JSESSIONID`.

**How can I enable Angular to send cookies?**

Answer (score 138, accepted):

In your config, DI `$httpProvider` and then set withCredentials to true:

```
.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    //rest of route code
})
```

Info on angularjs withCredentials: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http

Which links to the mozilla article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTTP_access_control#section_5

Comment: This and setting the backend header to Allow-Credentials fixed the problem! Thanks!

Comment: Just to add to this, I noticed when I did a call like `$http.get('something', { withCredentials: true})` the browser wouldn't send the cookies. However, using the above code to add `withCredentials` to the defaults did the trick. Not sure why but hopefully that helps if someone else runs across this problem

Comment: It still doesn't work for me. What I am doing is that the server set an httpOnly cookie on my first response, when I send the second request, the cookies set for the first response has never been attached to the second request.

Comment: It is working in localhost, but when I moved to a server it not working. Why it is not sending cookie in server?

Answer (score 11):

```
$http.get("URL", { withCredentials: true })
  .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {})
  .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {});
```

Another thing to keep in mind: You need to **have 3rd party cookies enabled**. If you have it globally disabled in Chrome, click on the "i"-Symbol to the left of the domain name, then cookies, then "blocked" and unblock the target domain.

Comment: This approach worked for me in AngularJS2....but not untill after the session I created before changing my source code expired!