# Angular2 replacement of $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have the exact same problem as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064791/http-doesnt-send-cookie-in-requests) question but for Angular 2.

To sum up, when sending an HTTP request to another domain, the JSESSIONID cookie is not sent along even if CORS headers are correctly set up.
The Angular 1.x solution is to set the following configuration:

```
.config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    //rest of route code
```

However I can't find any replacement solution for Angular 2.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: There's already an [open issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4231) about this, you can track it.

Comment: OK thanks I'll look for it!

Comment: FYI to keep working while it's not ready I disabled the checks on my local browser with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/

Answer (score 1):

You need to extend default Http service and set withCredentials to true

http.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Request, RequestOptions, Response, XHRBackend } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService extends Http {
  constructor(backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) {
    super(backend, options);
  }

  request(url: string | Request, options?: any): Observable<Response> {
    if (typeof url === 'string') {
        if (!options) {
            options = {headers: new Headers()};
        }
        options.withCredentials = true;
    } else {
        url.withCredentials = true;
    }

    return super.request(url, options);
  }
}
```

http.service.factory.ts

```
import { RequestOptions, XHRBackend } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpService } from './http.service';

export function HttpServiceFactory(backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
  return new HttpService(backend, defaultOptions);
};
```

and in your module file you need to replace your http service

```
import { HttpServiceFactory } from './http.service.factory';
import { Http, RequestOptions, XHRBackend } from '@angular/http';

...

providers: [
  {
    provide: Http,
    useFactory: HttpServiceFactory,
    deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you using Http service from import { Http,Response, Headers } from '@angular/http' you can set withCredentials: true;

```
post(params:string, obj:any): Observable<any> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("content-type", "application/json"); 
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl + params, JSON.stringify(obj), { headers: headers, withCredentials: true })
        .map((response : Response)=>{
                return response.json();
            });;           
}
```