# Cookies visible from HttpResponseMessage but not in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, cookies

I have a login service which passes user login information to my application when I login. This will call first page of my application on successful login. The user info is passed as part of a cookie in this request.

I am trying to read these cookies from the request in my Web API request using the below code.

```
 CookieHeaderValue getAccessUserInfo = request.Headers.GetCookies("GAUSERINFO").FirstOrDefault();

                if (getAccessUserInfo != null)
                {
                    userInfo = getAccessUserInfo["GAUSERINFO"].Values.Get("corporate_id");
                    Logger.Info(string.Format("User Cookie {0}", userInfo));
                    return userInfo;
                }
```

But if I am trying to read the same cookie from javascript or angular js, I am not able to see that cookie in the collection. 
Below is the code I am using to read the cookie in angular js.

```
console.log($document[0].cookie);
```

This is the cookie I can see from the result. The cookie I am expecting is GAUSERINFO along with the below cookies.

[image]

Is there a way to read these cookies from angular js or atleast pass that request body to the API so that I can read the cookie in my API using C# code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have access to HTTP only cookies for security reasons. In order to prevent [XSS attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), generally user session/login information should be HTTP only. If an attacker were to get the user's session information, they could impersonate the user. If you want to expose user info like `corporate_id` to the client side, it can be in a separate cookie that is not marked as HttpOnly.

From [MSDN for HttpCookie.HttpOnly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcookie.httponly):

> Stolen cookies can contain sensitive information identifying the user
>   to the site, such as the ASP.NET session ID or forms authentication
>   ticket, and can be replayed by the attacker in order to masquerade as
>   the user or obtain sensitive information. When an HttpOnly cookie is
>   received by a compliant browser, it is inaccessible to client-side
>   script.

To use `corporate_id` client side, create a separate cookie with the only the information you need client side and when you create it in your C# code be sure to set `HttpOnly` to false.

Edit: If your use case is to forward the cookie along to your API using Angular's $http service, there's additional configuration you can do for it which is detailed in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17065576/6950124

The summary of it being that you need to set `$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;` and potentially also configure your web server to send back the header `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` when the browser initially requests the page. This lets the browser know that your JavaScript code can have partial access to the HttpOnly cookies.

The underlying browser code for making the AJAX call should forward HttpOnly cookies if you have everything configured properly.

Comment: I’m not having any control on the service which sends me the cookies. I am trying to find a way to at least forward the content to my api through my browser if that’s possible.

Comment: HttpOnly is your problem. It is HttpOnly to prevent exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: @AshwiniMaddala Please see the edit to my answer. You may be able to configure angular and your web server to get this working without directly accessing the cookies in the JavaScript code.

Comment: Thanks @KevinSecrist. The login service is used across the organisation and is not customisable for every case. I have ended up changing the application into an angular+ mvc because we don’t have control over configuring the user login service.